# Passing data from PHP to Bootstrap modal

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a multi-store web-site that shows articles from a MySQL database.

There is a page which shows several articles, like this screenshot:

[image]

This is the current PHP code that shows the articles:

```
<?php

    $output .= '
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="margin-top:12px;">  
    <div class="item-content" >
    <div class="img-container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info "  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Info</button>
    <img src="../administrar/application/admin/productos/'.$row["image"].'" class="img-responsive" /><br />

    <h4 class="text-info" style= "color:#666">'.$row["nombre"].'</h4>
    
    <h4 class="text-info" style= "color:#000"><strong>'.$row["name"].'<strong></h4>
    <h5 class="text-info" style= "color:#000">'.$row['descripcion'].'</h5>
    <h4 class="text-danger" style= "color:#000">$ '.$row["price"] .'</h4>

    <input style= "color:#000" type="text" name="comentarios" id="comentarios' . $row["id"] .'"  placeholder="Special Instructions" class="form-control" value="" />
    <br>
    ';
```

You may see that there is a button to open a modal.

This is the piece of JavaScript code that opens the modal:

```
   // Get the modal de detallles de producto
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {

  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Here you have the modal content:

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #FF6600">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Product Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          
              <div class="container col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="../administrar/application/admin/productos/<?php echo $row["image"]?>" class="img-responsive" /><br />
                    </div>

                     <div class="col-md-6">
                           <h4 class="text-info" style= "color:#666"><?php echo $row["nombre"]?></h4>
                            <h4 class="text-info" style= "color:#000"><strong><?php echo $row["name"]?><strong></h4>
                     </div>

                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now, the issue is that the modal shows always the information from the last product inserted into the database, not the information from the selected product when the Info button is clicked.
This happens because the products are shown inside a while loop, and the modal only gets the data from the last product in the while loop.

How could I solve the issue and pass to the modal only the info from the selected product?

Comment: There's a couple of ways you could do it. 1), you could just write the HTML for all `n` modals and give each `div` a unique ID related to the info button. 2), you could use the same single modal but have placeholders instead of values. On click you could either AJAX in the values, or you could write the values as `data-` attributes on the info area.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, thank you for your proposal. I will option 2).